# Why does Wubi.exe for Ubuntu 11.10 not run on Windows 7 32bit?

Tags: windows-7, wubi, 32-bit

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 32bit before with the Wubi installer.I therefore completely uninstalled ubuntu and downloaded the new Ubuntu 11.10 32bit.But now When I  execute the Wubi.exe  it doesn't start.I just get a quick change of the mouse pointer showing that something happened but then nothing , no error messages. Can anyone help me?

=====
Summary of a discussion so far during the investigation:

are you absolutely sure you downloaded 32bit ubuntu 11.10? Are you sure you are using 32bit windows 7 and not 64bit windows? Did you do a md5sum checksum to confirm the ISO downloaded is valid and not corrupted?

hey i downloaded ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso & am sure about win7 32bit & iso image MD5 is : c396dd0f97bd122691bdb92d7e68fde5 i checked both hashes from ubuntu & mine both same

thats the desktop version... the MD5 sum looks ok. Did you use this webpage to download from? ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

i download it from ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download full .iso image not only wubi

what happens if you start wubi.exe from a command line?

if i write start H:\wubi.exe in cmd ...nothing happened without quick change of the mouse pointer showing that something happened

is this a standard PC or a work-environment PC? i.e. you do have administrator rights or some-sort of clampdown on windows 7?

i am only user & administrator of my pc & it is a standard pc

Comment: see .log file http://paste.ubuntu.com/790468/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my log files, I have:

`09-28 19:48 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Whereas you have:

`01-03 01:13 DEBUG WindowsBackend: startup_folder=None`

From analysis of the code, it appears that the bug is due to the fact that you don't have the startup folder set properly. 
To workaround this problem, set the startup environment variable by editing the registry (regedit) and make sure the following is set:
`'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'
                '\Explorer\Shell Folders',
                'Common Startup'`

And ensure the referenced folder exists i.e. `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

PS here is a reference to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/910948) (this shouldn't be a fatal problem).

Comment: bug reported...& did every possible way but still no luck

Answer (score 4):

at last problem solved.

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

accidentally this "startup" folder was deleted.just create this manually & wubi.exe runs.

> 09-28 19:48 DEBUG WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>
> 01-03 01:13 DEBUG WindowsBackend: startup_folder=None
>
> From analysis of the code, it appears that the bug is due to the fact that you don't have the startup folder set properly. To workaround this problem, set the startup environment variable by editing the registry (regedit) and make sure the following is set: 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion' '\Explorer\Shell Folders', 'Common Startup'
>
> I added a more detailed answer to the bug report including some code snippets.

thanks bcbc for your log it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user account in windows7 with administrative power. If you can extract iso using winRar or zip then your iso is not corrupted. Extract your iso in anywhere. Right click on wubi.exe and select run as admin.

Must uninstall and delete ubuntu folder from windows (previous installed ubuntu). If anything does not work then download just wubi.exe for ubuntu 11.10. Keep disconnect your internet during installation.

Comment: i did everything you told but no luck.also only wubi.exe does not open (online or offline)

Comment: try another way. Don't extract iso. Mount it using ultraISO or iso mounter apps. Try to run wubi.exe from virtual drive.

Comment: already did it.

Comment: Can you test the iso in another windows 7 pc? Do not install but just test that wubi.exe run.